# Annotation connectors blocking tooltips

Tags: svg, d3.js

I am creating a line plot with tooltips appearing on hovering over the data points using d3. However, I added a few annotations to the plot and the callout circles now block the tooltips from appearing on the points overlapped by the annotations.

The following is a screenshot of the tooltip appearing on the points, but it doesn't appear on the point overlayed by the annotation circle (grey circle on the image).

[image]

The code used to generate the line plot, the points, tooltip and annotations are as follows

```js
// Create Tooltip
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "tooltip")
    .style("position", "absolute")
    .style("z-index", "10")
    .style("visibility", "hidden")

// Annotations
const annotations = [
    {
        type: d3.annotationCalloutCircle,
        note: {
            label: "Label",
            title: "Title",
            wrap: 500 },
        subject: { radius: 40 },
        color: ["#bdbfbf"], x: 550, y: 100, dy: -50, dx: -120
    }
]

// Add annotations to the plot
const makeAnnotations = d3.annotation()
    .type(d3.annotationLabel)
    .annotations(annotations)
d3.select("svg")
    .append("g")
    .call(makeAnnotations)

// Draw line
var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x(+d.hour); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(+d.val); })
svg.selectAll(".line")
    .data(groupeddata)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .attr("stroke", function(d){ return color(d.key) })
    .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
    .attr("d", function (d){ return line(d.values)})

// Draw points and add tooltips
svg.selectAll(".dot")
    .data(groupeddata)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .style("fill", function(d){ return color(d.key) })
    .selectAll(".points")
    .data(function (d){return d.values})
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return x(d.hour) } )
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return y(d.val) } )
    .attr("r", 5)
    .attr("stroke", "white")
    .on("mouseover", function(d){
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible")
            .html("<b>" + d.day + " " + d.hour + "00h" + "</b>" + "<br/>"
                + "Average Pedestrian Count : " + parseFloat(d.val).toFixed(2))})
    .on("mousemove", function(){
        return tooltip.style("top",(d3.event.pageY-10)+"px")
            .style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px")})
    .on("mouseout", function(){
        return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden")})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contrast to HTML, SVG doesn't work with `z-index`, but just with the order of the elements in the HTML. Later nodes overlap any earlier nodes. One way to fix your issue would be to call [`.raise()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/#selection_raise) on all circles, so they are above the annotations and can thus be interacted with.

Another option is to check whether the annotation circle has `fill: none`. The following snippet shows how the first circle passes hovers to the rect behind it, while the second one doesn't. This is because `fill: none` literally removes the hitbox, while `fill:transparent` does not.

A final option is to add `pointer-events: none` to the annotation. That way, *all* events (hover, click, touch, drag, etc.) just pass through it as if it were a ghost.

Hover over the following nodes and see how they do or do not trigger a message in the console.

```js
d3.selectAll("rect")
  .on("mouseover", () => {
    console.log("HOVER");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg>
  <rect x="5" y="5" height="10" width="10"></rect>
  <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="10" stroke="black" fill="none"></circle>
  
  <rect x="45" y="5" height="10" width="10"></rect>
  <circle cx="50" cy="10" r="10" stroke="blue" fill="transparent"></circle>
  
  <rect x="85" y="5" height="10" width="10"></rect>
  <circle cx="90" cy="10" r="10" stroke="red" fill="transparent" style="pointer-events: none;"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks! All of the methods work fine! I added pointer-events: none to the annotation

Comment: Don't use fill: transparent; pointer-events is the preferred solution here.

Comment: @RobertLongson I added `fill: transparent` as an example of what *doesn't* work, not as something that should. If someone is unfamiliar with SVG, I thought this might be a common pitfall, given that it might work this way with HTML