# D3 mousemove event hovering wrong path element

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have D3 diagram with Nodes and Paths, when user selects path, it gets highlighted, in most situations, it works perfectly, but there's one case when I'm trying to hover `1` path and the `2` gets highlighted as shown in picture.

The paths are drawn in the `g` tag like:

```
<g class="links">
    ...
    <path class="link-path" id="explorer1-17" x1="787" y1="506" x2="1251" y2="681" marker-end="..." d="M787,506 1111,681 1251,681" marker-start="..." fill="transparent" style="cursor: pointer; stroke: rgb(18, 217, 47); stroke-width: 1;"></path>
    <path class="link-path" id="explorer1-18" x1="787" y1="496" x2="1251" y2="641.5" marker-end="..." d="M787,496 1111,641.5 1251,641.5" marker-start="..." fill="transparent" style="cursor: pointer; stroke: rgb(18, 217, 47); stroke-width: 2;"></path>
    ...
</g>
```

This issue happens when I hover the mouse closer to the angle, I debugged whole javascript and couldn't find any logic issues, so I think it's the dome related issue, any ideas?

[image]

Comment: please provide a [mcve] in your question. You should be able to do so via stack snippets.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Annotation connectors blocking tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64536153/annotation-connectors-blocking-tooltips) - it's because you used `fill: transparent`, which gives the paths a hitbox as if they were filled. Use `fill: none;` instead